# grep for capital words

Tags: grep

I have a file that has declarations in it with capital words, something like:

```
public final Foo BAR;
```

these declarations are not all uniform.  Is there a way for me to grep out just the capital lettered words from the line?  I know how to find lines that have capital letters in them, but thats not what I want.  I want only the matching capital lettered word.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered running [`ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net) on your source code and parsing that instead? You will avoid a lot of false-positive matches this way. For example, the solution you ask for will also show capitalized words in comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually with the `-o` switch, GNU `grep` returns only what it has matched. How about:

```
grep -oP "\w*[A-Z]+\w*" yourfile.txt
```

Note that this regex will match words with capital letters *anywhere* in them, not necessarily the beginning. You should tune it to meet your needs if they differ.

As pointed out below, this might not be the most portable of solutions. A portable alternative in Perl is

```
perl -nE 'say $1  while /(\w*[A-Z]+\w*)/g' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: That will match words that have a capital anywhere in the word, not necessarily at the beginning.

Comment: I am aware of that. The OP's example didn't specify capital letters in the beginning; in any case, by his use of grep, I was hoping he's comfortable enough with regex to use one more fine-tuned to his needs.

Comment: I wasn't saying that to imply that you were wrong, but as a clarification for people who don't parse PCRE with wetware.

Comment: Good point. Updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that this option is GNU specific and will not work on several implementations of `grep`. Using `sed` is the only portable way I know how to do this.

Comment: There's always Perl for those of us (like me) who are `sed`-challenged: `perl -e 'while(<>) {print "$1\n" while m/(\w*[A-Z]+\w*)/g};' yourfile.txt`

Comment: Or, even more elegantly, `perl -e 'print "$_\n" for map {m/(\w*[A-Z]+\w*)/g} <>'` yourfile.txt

Answer (score 6):

you could use `sed` to only return the string and not the whole line

```
sed 's/.*\([A-Z]*\).*/\1/g' <file>
```

or

```
sed 's/[a-z]*\| //g' <file>
```

Comment: You need to add a -n switch to suppress the input to be echoed to the output.

Answer (score 5):

The [POSIX Basic Regular expression standard](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (used by default in `grep`, `vim`, `less`, `sed`, etc.) uses `\<` and `\>` to signify word boundaries. This allows a letter to follow white-space, as well as non-alphanumeric characters like quotes, dashes, equal-signs, etc. Use the `-o` option to print each match on a new line, et voila:

```
grep -o '\<[A-Z][a-z]*\>' yourfile.txt
```

Again, you might need to have change the regexp to suit your needs. Maybe by allowing numbers or a second capital letter..? This does both..

```
grep -o '\<[A-Z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*\>' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Good one, thanks for the explanation on \< and \>!

Comment: No, `\<` is not in the POSIX spec of BREs. The link you provide is not to that spec but to  some man page of some version of GNU grep.